# Can we update client id and secret id with out code redeploy

Tags: azure-webjobs

Can we update webjobs client id and secret id with out re deploying solution in Azure Portal ? Please give suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the id and key in the Application settings.

[image]

And then use `System.getenv("client");`(I test with java) to get the value. I also update it as a WebJob, here is the log. It could show the client id.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if yous still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, we have console application using in SharePoint online and deployed in Azure , In Webapp we have 4 webjobs if we set the client id and secret id in Application settings how this will interact/effect  with particular webjob.   I did the changes in .exe.config file with updated client id and secret id in two webjobs  after that i am facing issues. one webjob -> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. Stack:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse(). Another webjob -> Error at Main: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Comment: @ user3436188, the application settings are effective foe the whole environment. So if you want different webjob use different ID or Keys, you could set the Id name with client_1 and the value must be different. You could also choose other client id name.

Comment: So we can do this with out re deploying solution. Before update I need to follow these please let me know if I missed any thing. 1) generated the client id 2) look up did based on appid 3) opened the app and trusted it. Finally I need to update client id in azure portal application settings?

Comment: @user3436188 , your flow is OK, and you could also use Azure KeyVault to store your ID and keys. It's more safer ,it's a azure service. You could refer to this doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/

Comment: @user3436188,any questions more? if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer.Thanks!